# Getting a bank account without a Norwegian fødselsnummer

Tags: banking, national-id-number, norway

The process of applying for a Norwegian fødselsnummer can take quite a while. At the same time, everything in Norway is paid by credit card which you cannot get without a bank account which in return requires the fødselsnummer. Are there any possibilities of getting a Norwegian bank account prior to receiving a fødselsnummer?

Comment: So how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to open a Norwegian bank account using a [D-number](http://www.skatteetaten.no/en/International-pages/Felles-innhold-benyttes-i-flere-malgrupper/Articles/Norwegian-national-ID-numbers/). This is basically a temporary (dummy) ID number for foreigners. There may be other requirements such as country of residence and (large) minimum deposit.

Of course, it takes time to [apply](http://www.brreg.no/blanketter/bin/d_nummer_eng.pdf) for this so if you plan to stay more than six months, you may as well apply for the real ID number (if applicable).

Comment: A problem with this solution is that you have to wait for the D-Number as well and it will delay the retrieval of the F-Number. Some institutions do not accept the D-Number either or charge higher fees. Also, it is hard to get medical care without a F-Number. Many people, especially out of Oslo don't even know what a D-Number is.